# Simple function in dynamic table

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I just learned how to create a function and display it inside a dynamic table - I think. I've been tweaking it, changing the variables, etc., but I can't get it to work.

I inserted the following script before the while loop.

```
function get_stars2($Latin)
{
$stars2 = ''; 
{ 
 switch($Latin) { 
    case 'Aix sponsa': 
    case 'Gavia immer': 
    return '<sup><span style="color: #f00;"><b>+</b></span></sup>'; 
    break; 
    default: 
    return $stars2;
    break;
  } 
 }
}
```

$Latin is actually defined inside the while loop, but I was told that doesn't matter; the function can take care of that outside the while loop.

And here's how I inserted the function inside the table:

```
<td>'.$row['Symbol'].'</a>'.get_stars2($Latin).$DesigAst.'</td>
```

---

Note: Someone commented that it's bad form to use functions to display HTML, so let me explain what's going on here. I was working on a rather complex dynamic reference table - actually a series of tables. One of my files was suffering from code bloat, so I put a series of PHP switches in a separate file and included them, using require_once. That was how I learned that require_once nixes the while loop; in other words, an action can only occur once. If I change require_once to require, then that entire file is included once for every row in my table.

So I asked about alternatives, and I was told I need to use a function, something I have very limited experience with. There were some other alternatives, but they were a little over my head. So I think I either need to learn how to work with functions or jazz up my database tables so they can handle all the extra annotation and footnotes in my reference tables.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with MySQL, so please remove the tag.

Comment: Why do you have brackets after `$stars2`?

Comment: Maybe you're not using `echo`. `return` is the right way to do it inside of the function, but it depends on an `echo` command being used outside of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why all of the convoluted logic?

> function get_stars2($Latin) {
>       if ($Latin) return '<sup><span style="color: #f00;"><b>+</b></span> </sup>';
>   }

Even better, you could just wrap it in

```
if ($Latin) { foo(); }
```

Also, it's considered bad form to have your PHP functions return HTML.

Also, your code works. Maybe you're not using the `echo` command.

Comment: Actually, I was echoing the code I originally posted. However, I replaced it without your code, and it actually works now. ;) "It's considered bad form to have your PHP functions return HTML." Well, this has been sort of a roller-coaster ride for me...I'll append an explanation to my original post.

Comment: `Also, it's considered bad form to have your PHP functions return HTML.` Really? How much experience you have? Look what he is showing. Think about it. PS: it's not `html` it's more like 'styling'...